# Calculations on Time Attribute in Apache Flink more than once

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

As the title says, I want to do calculations involving time attribute in a flink job more than once.The [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/time_attributes.html#introduction-to-time-attributes) mentions that once a time attribute is used in a calculation, it becomes a regular timestamp and unable to be used in a calculation again. Is there any way to use the time attribute twice or do I need to create another flink job for this purpose?

Comment: Could You elaborate on what exactly You want to obtain? This would make answering a lot easier.

Comment: You can use a time attribute more than once. What you can't do is to use the result of a calculation involving a time attribute as a time attribute. As the documentation says, you can forward a time attribute through to a view or result table. So long as it remains unmodified, you can use it again.

Comment: I wanted to use the result of the calculation as a time attribute again.